# Shared App Groups won't work with Developer ID & App Store signed App

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I'm struggling with this for a while now. Two OSX apps: One in in the App Store and the other one is a trial version signed with my Developer ID. Both have an app group enabled in their entitlements and of course "Outgoing Connections (Client)" enabled.

While the app group works fine in the App Store app (Can access files, etc.), the Developer ID signed app can't access that folder / files: NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256

I haven't found anything in the docs (yet), but I think it's just not possible to use App Groups in this way. Does anyone have a solution for this? How do I share data between an App Store app and a Developer ID app?

Best,
Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this. It seems like there is absolutely no way to exchange data.